# PDO Join across multiple Amazon RDS Databases from EC2

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am entertaining migrating my PHP/MySQL system over to Amazon Web Services. I have multiple MySQL Databases, currently managed by phpMyAdmin. I frequently have to cross query Databases, PDO Joins across two or more Databases in a single query.

If i migrated the code to EC2 and the database across to Amazon RDS, could I still cross query multiple databases using a single query in PHP / MySQL / PDO?

If so, can someone provide guidance on how this can be achieved. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If Amazon Web Services uses MySQL, I don't see why you wouldn't be able to. Did you check what type of a database Amazon RDS uses? RDS stands for a Relational DetabaSe, which is exactly what SQL is used on, so good chance you are just switching servers that support the same action.

Comment: PHP is common serverside code, and PDO is just one way to use PHP to work with a database, so I highly doubt any SDK amazon provides wouldn't allow you to use the most popular server side language in the world (I believe its the most popular haha, but don't quote me on that, it could be the Second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's nothing about RDS that would make this any different.

**RDS for MySQL is still MySQL Server.**

It's managed by AWS, on servers managed by AWS, which means you don't have access to the underlying OS, certain common administrative actions are disabled because they're managed by the RDS infrastructure,  some administrative commands normally reserved for users with `SUPER` privilege (which is not granted) are different (e.g. `KILL QUERY thread_id;` becomes `CALL mysql.rds_kill_query(thread_id);`) and some advanced capabilities like the `FEDERATED` storage engine and custom plugins are disabled...

But there's no reason any of the things you've mentioned wouldn't be exactly the same.

Comment: Yes! It's all set up. Where previously I was querying multiple databases, I am now using multiple schemas under one RDS Instance. The MySQL code is exactly the same so everything can just migrate across. Thanks!